# The Schema Generator: properties expecting several types

Tags: api-platform.com

In some cases, schema.org properties expect several types. For example: the [CreativeWork type](https://schema.org/CreativeWork) has a property called **author** which expect types **Organization** or **Person**.

Nevertheless, the Schema Generator requires a choice between them (using range option) or it will choose one by default and trigger the following message:

```
[warning] The property "author" (type "CreativeWork") has several types. Using the first one ("Organization") or possible options("Organization", "Person").
```

Currently, I plan to build an interface (e.g LegalPerson) which could be implemented by Organization and Person types and use it alongside Doctrine ResolveTargetEntityListener.

Is there any other practice to handle both types without dealing too much with generated source code ?

Cheers

Comment: Take schema as reference only, it's ideal for front end application but not that suitable for DataStructures. Use what is right for application in terms of storing the end data and utilize that to build up. Or simply do opposite and build from top to bottom. In your case You can have LegalPerson, ClerkPerson, ITPerson etc. extending Person via mapped super class or any other way, referencing User and Organization it belongs to. Choice of Table type depends if it can be combined into one for performance or use Expensive joins in favour of Readability.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your valuable feedback.  I'll follow these guidelines.